# How to assign Leads to two different queues available in the ratio of 60% and 40% (Round robin)

Tags: apex

I am having two queues "GOLD" and "Platinum" which are having separate group of users.
Now I wanted to assign 40% of the total leads to GOLD queue and rest 60% of the total to PLATINUM queue which all are coming from web-to-lead.
For eg. Suppose if we are getting 10 leads at a time then assign 4 to GOLD queue and 6 to PLATINUM queue.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the topic [How do I create a round-robin assignment for Leads or Cases to users?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004000), the basic idea has to be extended to support your desired ratio.

The easiest way to do this is to alter the Round_Robin_ID__c formula field suggested in the help document:

```
IF(MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c), 10) < 4, 0, 1)
```

Here, we'll return 0 if the number ends in 0, 1, 2, or 3 (4 of 10 digits), otherwise return 1 if the number ends in 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 (6 of 10 digits). You can extend this logic out as far as you need to; if you wanted to change it to 45/55, you could use 100 as the base divisor, and check for less than 45 instead.

If you'd rather assign leads more pseudo-randomly, you could mix it up with CASE:

```
CASE(MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c), 10), 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 1)
```

Where numbers ending in 0, 3, 6, or 8 comprise the 40%, and numbers ending in 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, and 9 comprise the 60% (or any other way you'd like to split it up).